# Random selection from array list

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I want to select a student randomly for `messfood()`. Trying to print the student name there.Each week, any of the student should be selected for mess food charge. Tried with `String random = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));`. But is shows error. Help me with this.

```
public class Student {
int rollNo, yearOfStudy;
String fName, lName, activity;

Student(int rollNo, String fName, String lName, int yearOfStudy) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;
}
public void display(){
    System.out.println("Roll Number: "+rollNo +"\nName: "+fName+ " "+lName + "\nYear Of Study: "+yearOfStudy+"\n\n");

}
public void messFood(){
    System.out.println("week 1, Mess food Incharge: ");

}

}

class Collection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s1 = new Student(1, "Alex", "Iwobi", 2013);
    Student s2 = new Student(2, "Denis", "Suarez", 2013);
    Student s3 = new Student(3, "Gerard", "Deulofeu", 2013);
    Student s4 = new Student(4, "Petr", "Cech", 2013);



    List studentList = new ArrayList();
    studentList.add(s1);
    studentList.add(s2);
    studentList.add(s3);
    studentList.add(s4);


    Iterator it = studentList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Student s=(Student)it.next();
        s.display();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You are using a raw collection and expecting a `String` instead of a `Student`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Naturally, reading the error message may help.

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why you should be using generics!  You risk to encounter runtime errors (as opposed to compile-time errors) involving expected and actual types.

Your call to `list.get()` will return `Object` if generics are not used, requiring you therefore to cast it.  If the cast happens to be *wrong* as in your case, it will explode only when run.  If you were using generics, your compiler would have told you that you can't convert a `Student` type to `String` type!

Take a look at my version:

```
public class Student {
    int rollNo, yearOfStudy;
    String fName, lName, activity;

    public Student(int rollNo, String fName, String lName, int yearOfStudy) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder()
            .append("Roll Number: ").append(rollNo)
            .append("\nName: ").append(fName).append(" ").append(lName)
            .append("\nYear Of Study: ").append(yearOfStudy)
            .append("\n\n")
            .toString();
    }

    public void messFood() {
        // Establish mess food charge role
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "Alex", "Iwobi", 2013);
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "Denis", "Suarez", 2013);
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Gerard", "Deulofeu", 2013);
        Student s4 = new Student(4, "Petr", "Cech", 2013);

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);
        studentList.add(s4);

        Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Student s = it.next();
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }

        Student randomStudent = getRandomItem(studentList);
        randomStudent.messFood();
        System.out.println("week 1, Mess food Incharge: ");
        System.out.println(randomStudent.toString());
    }

    private static <T> T getRandomItem(List<T> studentList) {
        return studentList.get(new Random().nextInt(studentList.size()));
    }
}
```

Also, in addition to generics, I added a couple of best practices, namely prefering the use of `toString()` to describe the class rather than printing it out directly (you can do with the `String` whatever you want afterwards, including calling `System.out.println()`) .

Also I moved out printing from `messFood` because again, it is generally preferable to do so.  Hope that helps!

**Edit**:  Describing briefly `getRandomItem`, try not to get too caught up in the details, but `<T>` says that there will be a type to replace `T` according to how it will be called.  Based on how it is defined, it says if you pass me a `List` containing type `T`, I will return to you an object `T`.  `T` in this case translates to `Student`, but I kept it generic because it works equally well with other lists.  For all intents and purposes, it is as if the signature were the following:

```
private static Student getRandomItem(List<Student> studentList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.get()
```

will return a student object and not a string, assuming that it's a list of students.

You should do

```
Student random = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
System.out.println(random.getFname + " " + random.getLname);
```

But of course you need get methods defined.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. You should show to the OP the correct way to proceed, not just what he did wrong.